How to uninstall software from linux mint?
From the terminal  I install (Blender). now I am trying to uninstall it But I can't. After shut down it comes back again. Not only this software, every software that I installed from terminal.


How did you install it from the terminal?

I tried Using  commands to uninstall, but nothing happens.

No, I asked about how you installed the software.

Using commands from snap stor

Please update you text with the exakt command you used to install the software as well as the commands you have used to try to uninstall the software. If there were error messages as result of any command, then also show this without altering the output in any way.

Not nearly enough information. Read this closely and carefully: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#intro How did you install it? From where? Using what? How are you trying to uninstall it? Using what? Be specific, precise and accurate. Give all the details you can.

To remove Blender installed from Snap completely, use:
sudo snap remove --purge blender


Thank you, It worked.
